# Stop Ursina engine from calling update function

Tags: python, ursina

How can I make the Ursina engine stop calling `update()` function every frame after a certain condition while also running rest of the script

The `application.quit()` terminates my script and `app.destroy()` just closes the window, while still calling `update()` every frame.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle this case in your `update()` function in the form of a [guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_%28computer_science%29):

```py
def update():
    if condition:
        return
    # normal code...
```